# Generate json key as snake_case with RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, restsharp

Any idea how to generate json key as `snake_case` with `RestSharp`?

With `Newtonsoft.Json`, I can set json output something like this

```cs
  DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = contractResolver,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            });
```

But I not sure how can be done with `RestSharp`

```cs
var client = new RestClient(getService.MstUrl);

            client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST).AddJsonBody(requestData);          

            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

It keep generate as `camelCase`. Is there any configuration like `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RestSharp, does not mean you can't use the `Newtonsoft` serializer as well.

From the [restsharp documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage/serialization.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net):

> RestSharp support Json.Net serializer via a separate package. You can install it from NuGet.

```
client.UseNewtonsoftJson();
```

And keep on going with what you did:

```
DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create your own `IRestSerializer` implementation and supply that in `client.UseSerializer`

**Given**

```
public class SimpleJsonSerializer : IRestSerializer
{
   private readonly DefaultContractResolver _contractResolver;

   public SimpleJsonSerializer()
   {
      _contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
      {
         NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
      };   
   }
   public string Serialize(object obj) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
      ContractResolver = _contractResolver,
      Formatting = Formatting.Indented
   });

   public string Serialize(Parameter bodyParameter) => Serialize(bodyParameter.Value);

   public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);

   public string[] SupportedContentTypes { get; } =
   {
      "application/json", "text/json", "text/x-json", "text/javascript", "*+json"
   };

   public string ContentType { get; set; } = "application/json";

   public DataFormat DataFormat { get; } = DataFormat.Json;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var client = new RestClient(getService.MstUrl);

client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
client.UseSerializer(() => new SimpleJsonSerializer(){});

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST).AddJsonBody(requestData);

var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : I haven't used `RestSharp` in years and I never intend to use it again. Further more, I really do suggest to anyone thinking of using it to switch back to `HttpClient`, or even better `IHttpClientFactory`. More so, this is completely untested, and only given as an example. You may need to modify it to it your needs*</sub>

Comment: Can share your experience why not use `RestSharp` anymore?